# Kohana auto_login not working

Tags: php, kohana

I noticed today that the auto login for the Auth module in Kohana does not work. I snooped around a little and I think I found the problem.

The authautologin token is saved in a cookie and the database just fine whenever I login with "remember me" enabled. However, everytime I logout, the cooie gets destroyed.

Looking in the Auth library, I saw that everytime you logout, the user is deleted from the session, AND the token is deleted from the cookie. In the auto login function, The authautologin cookie is necessary to work. Also, the token is deleted from the database with every logout.

Am I wrong or is something missing/incorrect about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, everytime I logout, the cooie gets destroyed.

Of course, you don't want them to stay logged in forever do you.

Auto-login is meant for people who close their browsers without logging out. When they re-open the browser their session is resumed.

Answer (score 2):

that's how every login system works. look at google gmail system if i dont click logout i'm still signed in even if i reboot my system. if i click logout i'm not signed in anymore.

my solution for you, don't click the logout button